# Left JOIN query not displaying data

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

```
SELECT Name,Checktime 
FROM Userinfo 
LEFT JOIN Checkinout ON USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID 
WHERE Checktime >= #11/14/18 04:35:00 AM#;
```

The above query has to display all name from `userinfo` table but it only displays matching data with checkinout table.

[image: Here is my table]

Comment: ofcourse it will show from checkinout table because you are using `RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: Even, i changed to left JOIN still am getting same data

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images (or links to images...)

Comment: Ms access, i have added an image

Comment: If you remove the WHERE clause, do you get any result? The expected result?

Comment: REmoved, it displays all dates result

Comment: Do you see any rows with `Checktime>=#11/14/18 04:35:00 AM#`?

Comment: Yes, i just have to show all the Name from userinfo table and today's checkintime.

Comment: At the end, now add `AND Checktime>=#11/14/18 04:35:00 AM#;`, to include the condition in the ON clause! (Instead of in the WHERE clause.)

Comment: It says, join expression does not supported

Comment: we have 209 employees it only displays 196 names who are presented on 11/14/2018. It should displays all employees name and their checktime on 11/14/2018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most databases, you would move the condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT ui.Name, cio.Checktime 
FROM Userinfo as ui LEFT JOIN
     Checkinout as cio
     ON ui.USERID = cio.USERID AND
        cio.Checktime >= #11/14/18 04:35:00 AM#;
```

Alas, this standard syntax is not supported in MS Access.  You can use a subquery instead:

```
SELECT ui.Name, cio.Checktime 
FROM Userinfo as ui LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT cio.*
      FROM Checkinout as cio
      WHERE cio.Checktime >= #11/14/18 04:35:00 AM#
     ) as cio
     ON ui.USERID = cio.USERID ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question title says `LEFT JOIN not working` but in your query, you are using `RIGHT JOIN`?

Just use `LEFT JOIN` in your query. It will list all users from `USERINFO` but only matching records from `CHECKINOUT`.

```
SELECT `Name`, `Checktime`
FROM `Userinfo`
LEFT JOIN `Checkinout` ON `USERINFO`.`USERID` = `CHECKINOUT`.`USERID`
Where `Checktime` >= #11/14/18 04:35:00 AM#;
```

Comment: No, still same data

Comment: Add sample data from both tables in your question then I will be able to comment further.

Comment: Please check the image

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display all name from the userinfo and display the match data from the checkinout table you just need to change RIGHT JOIN to LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT Checkinout.USERID, Userinfo.Name, Userinfo.Checktime,
FROM Userinfo
LEFT JOIN Checkinout ON USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID
WHERE Checktime >= #11/14/18;
```

Try this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can set alias on each table

```
SELECT a.*,b.* 
FROM Userinfo  a
LEFT JOIN Checkinout b ON a.USERID = b.USERID 
Where b.Checktime>=#11/14/18 04:35:00 AM#;
```